# Complex number, how to solve

Tags: complex-numbers

Calculate

i)$(1+i)^i$

ii)$(-1)^{\frac{1}{\pi}}$

I did

i)$(1+i)=\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}}$. Knowing that if $z$ and $c$ are complex numbers $z^c=e^{c\log z}$
$$(1+i)^i=e^{i\log(1+i)}=i\log(1+i)=i\log(\sqrt{2}e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})=i\log\sqrt{2}-\frac{\pi}{4}$$

That's right?

What property should I use in item 2?

I again tried to question two and got it

$(-1)=e^{i\pi}$
$$(-1)^\frac{1}{\pi}=e^{\frac{1}{\pi}\log(e^{i\pi})}=\frac{1}{\pi}log(e^{i\pi)}=\frac{1}{\pi}i\pi=i$$

Comment: should you not have  $1 + i = \sqrt 2 e^{i(\pi/4 + 2k\pi)}$ instead with $k$ any integer.

Comment: @abel I think this would not be necessary. How can I solve the second item?

Comment: Depends, @abel. Defining $x^y=e^{y\log x}$, some definitions use some principle value of $\log x$ and others consider a multi-valued definition. Multivalued is probably the more mathematically sound method, for a variety of reasons.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews   thanks . i suppose it an agreed upon convention.

Comment: @askazy I really want to help here, so please let me know if there is any way I can improve my answer.  I just want to provide the best answer I can give you.

Comment: You wrote $$e^{i\log(1+i)} = i\log(1+i)$$ which is clearly wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first case, $(1+i)^i$ we may write
$$\begin{align}
(1+i)^{i}&= (\sqrt{2}e^{i(\pi /4 + 2n\pi)})^{i} \\
&=\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^{i}e^{-(\pi /4+2n\pi)}\\
&=e^{-(\pi /4+2n\pi)}\left(e^{\log(\sqrt{2})}\right)^{i}\\
&=e^{-(\pi /4+2n\pi)}e^{i\log(\sqrt{2})}\\
&=e^{-(\pi /4+2n\pi)}\left(\cos(\log(2)/2)+i\sin(\log(2)/2)\right)
\end{align}$$

where $n$ is any integer ($n=0$ on the principal branch).

For the second case, $(-1)^{1/\pi}$ we may write
$$\begin{align}
(-1)^{1/\pi}&= (e^{i(2n+1)\pi})^{1/\pi}\\
&=e^{i(2n+1)}\\
&=\cos(2n+1)+i\sin(2n+1)
\end{align}$$

where $n$ is any integer ($n=0$ on the principal branch).

Comment: My solution in i) is wrong?

Comment: You forgot to raise $e$ to the last expression you have.  And you only have the solution on the principal branch (which is a legitimate solution, just not the only one; there are a countable infinite number of solutions.)

Comment: You can solve step by step $e^{ilog(\sqrt{2})}$

Comment: @askazy What steps?  Euler's identity is one step.

Answer (score 1):

let me see if $$z = (-1)^{1/\pi} \to \ln z = \frac 1{\pi} \ln(-1) = \frac 1{\pi} \ln (e^{i\pi})=\frac 1{\pi}(i\pi) = i $$ works. yes, it does.
therefore, $$ z = e^{i}=\cos 1 + i \sin 1.$$

Comment: Why does $\pi (i \pi)=-i \pi^2 \text{ and not } i \pi^2$?

Comment: Why you use $z=(-1)^\pi$? The correct expression is $(-1)^\frac{1}{\pi}$

Comment: And I'm also having a small problem with the therefore part. $e^z=e^{i \cdot - \pi^2}=\cos(- \pi^2)+i \sin(-\pi^2)=\cos(\pi^2)-i \sin(\pi^2)$

Comment: @randomgirl, thanks for spotting the error. that was a mistake.  corrected now.

Comment: @abel I can not understand what you did. Why you use $z=(-1)^\pi$?

Comment: isn't the question $(-1)^{1/\pi}$? @abel

Comment: @ThomasAndrews,  all. it is spring break at my school.